# Mysqldb Update error with set %s

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have created a database with MySQLdb.
In database I have a table with name `student` with columns:

```
id(is int),
id_user(is int),
f_name(is str),
l_name(is str)
```

I want to update a row.
My code is below:

```
db=mdb.connect(host="localhost", use_unicode="True", charset="utf8", 
               user="", passwd="", db="test")                          
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

sql="""SELECT id_user FROM student"""

try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   db.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()

rows = cursor.fetchall()

the=int(7)
se=str('ok')
for row in rows:
    r=int(row[0])
    if r==the:          
        sql2 = """UPDATE student
                SET f_name=%s
                WHERE id_user = %s"""% (se,the)

               # Execute the SQL command
        cursor.execute(sql2)
        # Commit your changes in the database
        db.commit()

        db.rollback()
# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

When I run it I take the error there is column with name ok why?
Can anyone help me find what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: You should enclose strings into single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run the query like this:

```
sql2 = """UPDATE student
          SET f_name = %s
          WHERE id_user = %s"""
cursor.execute(sql2, (se, the))
```

Don't use string interpolation, let the database driver handle passing the parameters for you.  Otherwise you have to deal with syntax errors like this, or worse, SQL injection.

More details [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiFaq#How_do_I_pass_parameters_to_the_cursor.execute_method.3F).

Comment: I dont know what code to use yours or ruakh.I will see that later :)

Comment: You should always pass the parameters like this, constructing the SQL manually is just adding more problems for no reason.

Answer (score 3):

`str` doesn't wrap its argument in quotation marks, so your statement is this:

```
UPDATE student SET f_name=ok WHERE id_user = 7
```

when it needs to be this:

```
UPDATE student SET f_name='ok' WHERE id_user = 7
```

So, either change this line:

```
                SET f_name=%s
```

to this:

```
                SET f_name='%s'
```

or else change this line:

```
se=str('ok')
```

to this:

```
se="'" + str('ok') + "'"
```

Though I recommend reading about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which will become a concern as soon as you start using user-supplied data instead of hard-coded values.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation, although -- as @Lukas mentions -- the DB-API should really be used here; as you allude to with the SQL injection comment

Answer (score 0):

You should always enclose your data with quotes.

Instead of %s solely use '%s' the only types you dont need it are numeric ones, but even there i would enclose %d with '%d' cos it is more save.

And you should use at least db.escape_string(your_data) before inserting or updating same values into your database.

Or have a look at the pdo-using style of mysqldb:

http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples

```
c=db.cursor()
max_price=5
c.execute("""SELECT spam, eggs, sausage FROM breakfast
      WHERE price < %s""", (max_price,))
```